# extend the storage of a beaglebone black

Tags: mount, storage, sd-card

I've got a beaglebone black rev B (2gb storage) and I want to use it to run owncloud as a self-hosted cloud. The beaglebone comes with 2gb of storage, which means that it has just enough room for the beaglebone version of debian, but installing owncloud (plus dependencies) takes an additional 260MB, which the beaglebone doesn't have, so apt-get exits with an error.

I have a 1TB external hard drive and a 16GB SD card with which I can boost the storage, but I'm not quite sure of the best way to proceed. I was planning on just mounting the hard drive to /home and using it only for the actual cloud storage, but would it be possible/wise to move something else there too? /bin maybe? It is only connected by USB2 so it might be too slow? Using the SD card is another option, but from what I've read SD cards are fairly crap. Again though, I'm faced with the same problem, if I did go down the root of using the SD card and saving the external HDD for just /home, what would be the most suitable place to mount onto the SD card?

Comment: Get an 8Gb MicroSD card, put the BB Debian image on that, then put it in the BB, boot up and follow this web site: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:Expanding_File_System_Partition_On_A_microSD